# Do I need to take a backup before installing Ubuntu through Wubi?

Tags: ubuntu, wubi, ubuntu-12.10

I have a PC with Windows 7 Ultimate and Ubuntu 10.04 with GRUB as boot manager.

Now I would like to install Ubuntu 12.10 along with these operating systems. I prefer Wubi, as it seems easy to install Ubuntu without harming the other OS.

Do I need to back up all my files? Or can I switch to the new version of Ubuntu/Windows 7/Ubuntu 10.04 from GRUB?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to back up all my files?

No need to backup files.

> Or can I switch to the new version of Ubuntu/Windows 7/Ubuntu 10.04 from GRUB?

Yes, you can. The GRUB menu lists your old OS for booting like this:

[image]

What are the possible problems? Sometimes [Ubuntu might not appear in your boot menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208145/ubuntu-12-04-installed-using-wubi-not-showing-up-at-boot-time-after-windows-r).